# single positional indexer is out-of-bounds: an error

Tags: python, pandas

why dataframe.iloc[1,5] return an error but dataframe.iloc[[1,5]] not?

Comment: share your dataframe..!

Comment: Because `dataframe.iloc[1,5]` means the cell at coordinate `(1, 5)`, but `dataframe.iloc[[1,5]]` means rows 1 and 5. Did you try using a larger example input, in order to see what each one does when there is no error? Did you try to read the error message, in order to understand what the problem is?

Comment: Anyway, please read [ask] and [mre] and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Before seeking help with an error on Stack Overflow, **read** the error message and try to understand it; look for a cause by carefully studying what happens when the code runs; then create a **small** example that **directly** demonstrates the problem. Make sure others can **copy and paste it without adding or changing anything**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataframe.iloc[1,5]` returns an error because it is trying to access a single scalar value at the intersection of row 1 and column 5 in the DataFrame.

On the other hand, `dataframe.iloc[[1,5]]` does not return an error because it is trying to access multiple rows (rows 1 and 5) in the DataFrame. In this case, the output is a new DataFrame containing those specific rows.

The `.iloc` attribute is used to access a specific location in the DataFrame by index position. When passing a single integer value to `.iloc`, it will treat it as the index of the row, and when passing a list of integers, it will treat it as the indices of the rows.

So in short, when you use `dataframe.iloc[1,5]` it's trying to access a single value at a specific location, which doesn't exist in the dataframe. But when using `dataframe.iloc[[1,5]]` you're accessing the rows with those indexes, which exist in the dataframe.